# Logrotate does not work for httpd service

Tags: centos, cron

We have logrotate working for several Centos servers. One new server has a slightly different setup, and for some reason logrotate does not work for the httpd service. When I start it manually, it does work as expected. I've set this up last week, and it didn't run once in four days.

The file /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exists, so I guess the cron job should run daily.

Contents of /etc/logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

Contents of /etc/logrotate.d/httpd. I suppose these override the logrotate.conf settings.

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    daily
    compress
    rotate 20
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Do you have cron service running? logrotate gets launched by cron, in CentOS with the file `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`. Also, what are the symptoms why is not working? Where are the logs that are not rotated?

Comment: As I explained in the question, when I run logrotate manually, it works, so the location of the logs is set properly. However, when I try a test cron script, that does not run.

Comment: I've changed my question as it appears to be a cron problem!

Comment: can you check /var/log/cron, also syntax is correct, do you have permissions to write into /home/john/crontest.txt ? what you get from cli when you issue following commnad ?

Comment: I see this in the cron log: `(root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Module is unknown)`. I can run the test script from the CLI.

Comment: Yesterday we had to restart the server because of other problems, and now the cron works. @PabloMartinez - if you want the points, create an answer!

Comment: No need for the points, happy to know that is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron was not running. After a restart the cron worked, and logrotate started to work as well.